# Problems with adding an event handler to a resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

All I wanted was to add an event handler to a button style, defined in a resource dictionary.

ResDict.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
                x:Class="MyProject.ResDict" >

    //other stuff here

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="close_event" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

ResDict.xaml.cs (<= I added this file manually)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class ResDict : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public ResDict()
        {
            //InitializeComponent(); <-- If I uncomment this, the compiler cannot find it
        }
        private void close_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //This is what the event handler is intended to be, but the compiler seems to not know it.
            //'ResDict' does not contain a definition for 'close_event' and no extension method 'close_event' accepting a first argument of type 'ResDict' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

        }
    }
}
```

The compiler cannot find the event handler. I have discovered that in the obj/Debug folder there are two files (ResDict.g.cs and ResDict.g.i.cs), which contain a `public partial class ResDict`, but since they are not included in the project, the compiler thinks of those classes and mine (ResDict) as separate classes, and I think this is the reason why InitializeComponent cannot be found (it is defined in those files). However I don't want to include those files because that comes with a ton of compile-time errors. I don't want to add the event handler to them either 
because they are auto-generated files.

My question:
How/where can I add the event handler? And what about InitializeComponent? How do I tell the compiler that it is defined in some auto-gen files?

Let me know if the question is unclear.

Comment: `ResourceDictionary` doesn't have a `InitializeComponent()` method, so you don't need to call it. VS *created* those *.g.cs classes as intermediate files; no need to worry that it doesn't know about them. I was able to get the event handler in your code to work, though. Are ResDict.xaml and ResDict.xaml.cs in the same folder in the solution? Did you try a clean build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours, I realised that the actual problem was a sneaky **typo** (w instead of W) in the name of the namespace. It was of course irreproducable then.